# How to Execute Updates in Parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I noticed that when I use `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` as compared to `new Promise((resolve, reject))`, it is executing the query and I am getting my desired result on my `Promise.all([]).then` block like:

```
      const borrowersFeePromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (borrowersFee !== undefined && borrowersFee !== '') {
          const borrowersFeeUpserted = await Fees.update(
            {
              personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
              category: 'borrowersFee',
            },
            {
              $set: {
                amount: borrowersFee,
              },
            },
            { upsert: true },
          );
          resolve({
            upsert: borrowersFeeUpserted,
            hasPassed: true,
          });
        } else {
          resolve({
            upsert: null,
            hasPassed: true,
          });
        }
      });

      const extendedFeePromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (extendedFee !== undefined && extendedFee !== '') {
          const extendedFeeUpserted = await Fees.update(
            {
              personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
              category: 'extendedFee',
            },
            {
              $set: {
                amount: extendedFee,
              },
            },
            { upsert: true },
          );
          resolve({
            upsert: extendedFeeUpserted,
            hasPassed: true,
          });
        } else {
          resolve({
            upsert: null,
            hasPassed: true,
          });
        }
      });

      await Promise.all([
        borrowersFeePromise,
        extendedFeePromise,
      ]).then((feesResult) => {
        console.log(feesResult);

        /*
          outputs something like:
          [ { upsert: { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }, hasPassed: true },
            { upsert: { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }, hasPassed: true } ]
        */
      });
```

However, when I just use `new Promise((resolve, reject)`, it doesn't execute the query and it outputs something like:

```
 [   { upsert:
    Query {
      _mongooseOptions: {},
      mongooseCollection: [Object],
      model: [Object],
      schema: [Object],
      op: 'update',
      options: [Object],
      _conditions: [Object],
      _fields: undefined,
      _update: [Object],
      _path: undefined,
      _distinct: undefined,
      _collection: [Object],
      _traceFunction: undefined,
      _count: [Function],
      _execUpdate: [Function],
      _find: [Function],
      _findOne: [Function],
      _findOneAndRemove: [Function],
      _findOneAndUpdate: [Function],
      _replaceOne: [Function],
      _updateMany: [Function],
      _updateOne: [Function] },
   hasPassed: true },
 ....]
```

I thought promises are meant to wait for execution, but why does it only execute when I put `async (resolve, reject)`? My intention are for those two fees to execute at the same time when I run `Promise.all`, like non-blocking commands. It is how I understand Promises after watching and rewatching tutorials about it. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you wrapping in a Promise anyway? ALL the methods on the mongoose API **already return a Promise.** In fact you are already awaiting them. Why you think you need to do what you are doing is actually really baffling.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, that is why I am asking, because I saw a tutorial about Promise.all which executes commands simultaneously and I want that to execute both my mongoose update command at the same time... so I use Promise.all.

Comment: There's a much better approach to what you are trying to do. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is what you actually want:

```
await Promise.all([
  Fees.update(
        {
          personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
          category: 'borrowersFee',
        },
        {
          $set: {
            amount: borrowersFee,
          },
        },
        { upsert: true },
  ),
  Fees.update(
        {
          personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
          category: 'extendedFee',
        },
        {
          $set: {
            amount: extendedFee,
          },
        },
        { upsert: true },
  )
])
```

But really, you **should** be doing this instead:

```
let results = await Fees.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": { 
    "filter": {
      personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
      category: 'borrowersFee',
    },
    "update": { $set: { amount: borrowersFee } },
    "options": { upsert: true },
 }},
 { "updateOne": { 
    "filter": {
      personId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(personId),
      category: 'extendedFee',
    },
    "update": { $set: { amount: extendedFee } },
    "options": { upsert: true },
 }}
],{ "ordered": false })
```

Using the [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) method means **"one"** request send over the wire to the server instead of the **"two"** required by executing separate statements to resolve in parallel. So not only is their reduced overhead that makes it faster, but the `{ "ordered": false }` makes sure these actually run parallel *"on the server"*.

Comment: FYI bulkWrite skips all middleware. Validation is also a middleware. I believe that will get skipped as well. Potentially should only do this for seed data, but probably not really for that that either since you want to make sure you're inserting valid seed data.

Comment: @GovindRai I probably should have included the disclaimer. IMHO the benefits greatly outweigh the loss of "validation" etc. In performance applications you don't actually do that "per object" but rather check the "batch" of data to submit first. Making 1000's of requests simply because you want a "validator" in your schema to fire is actually a ludicrous suggestion. So **"prefferred"** is to do what I say here. And I might just have some depth of experience with it as well.